# Make a Directory witout prompt

Tags: file, directory

this is my first question.

I follow your Intruction example and created this batch

```
set name=%Date:/=_%

xcopy /s/y "C:\user\DebugLogs\*.*" "%C:\user\Desktop\LOG BACKUP\%name%"
```

It works great for my job but when prompt it ask to specify D)Directory or F)File

What can I add to the batch that always do Directory with no Prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Put an ending slash for your output location as in:

xcopy /s/y "C:\user\DebugLogs*.*" "%C:\user\Desktop\LOG BACKUP\%name%\"

That will tell xcopy to place all files into the specified directory.